# Google map shows up quite blurry on high pixel density device like htc one x, is there any way to fix this?

Tags: c#, javascript, html, google-maps, dictionary

I am embedding google map in one of my mobile website. The map shows up quite blurry on my htc one x device, but somehow the map in map.google.com is quite sharp.

I would think there is some settings in my GA map API which will allow me to specify density or image size. But I've tried looking over the net and wasn't able to find it. Does anyone have any ideas how this can be resolved? Below is the code i use..

```
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: zoomlvl,
        center: myLatlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        mapTypeControl: false

    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

   var image = 'beachflag.png';
    var beachMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: myLatlng,
          map: map
          icon: image
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears this to be resolved by itself. The issue seems to be the google API. It goes away as the code points to the latest Gmap API.